# Google maps marker clustering for array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know there are a bunch of questions on this subject already - but I have read many of them but can't seem to get anything working in my particular case. I want to make a map with a bunch of custom markers with info windows showing store locations across Australia (<-- this part i have working)...
When zoomed out the markers should group by city with a number shown... also I would like a html list of links that when clicked zoom to an particular marker on the map. Much like the example shown here: https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/examples/speed_test_example.html

Below is my code (at the moment I have just added locations in 2 cities as example, later to have many cities nationwide):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Locations</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var infowindow = null;
    $(document).ready(function () { initialize();  });

    function initialize() {

        var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274398, 133.775136);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: centerMap,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);

        setMarkers(map, sites);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "loading..."
            });

    }

    var sites = [
    ['location 16', -37.814107 , 144.96328, 6, 'Description in info window','images/map_mobile.png'],
    ['location 5', -37.911394 , 145.189584, 5, 'Description in info window','images/map_store.png'],
    ['location 4', -33.963542 , 151.134273, 4, 'Description in info window','images/map_store.png'],
    ['location 3', -33.923960 , 150.921158, 3, 'Description in info window','images/map_store.png'],
    ['location 2', -34.065619 , 150.796491, 2, 'Description in info window','images/map_mobile.png'],
    ['location 1', -33.752178 , 150.6910478, 1, 'Description in info window','images/map_mobile.png']
];

    function setMarkers(map, markers) {

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var sites = markers[i];
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: sites[0],
                zIndex: sites[3],
                html: sites[4],
                icon: sites[5]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                //alert(this.html);
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map" style="width: 620px; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So in summary, I need help with getting the clustering working and html links...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array "sites" was undefined in your code, I wonder why though... but I'm no expert in javascript...
If you move it inside your `initialize()` function, it works correctly.

The declaration of the MarkerClusterer doesn't include any markers, which doesn't make sense at all. Based on the examples in here https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html you can see that you need to first declare your markers, then include them in the declaration of the MarkerClusterer.

Also in your `setMarkers()` function you declare a local variable "sites", this is dangerous as you also have a global one with the same name. (it's not the case anymore since I moved it within `initialize()`)

Finally, I don't know what you intent to do with the infowindow, right now, nothing is displayed, but if you write `infowindow.setContent('Hello Marker');` instead of "this.html", it will work.

You can find a working example of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/839dV/

Comment: Thanks very much, you have the knowledge that i do not. Good job.

Comment: Any idea about making a list in the same page below the map that jumps to the relevant map marker and opens the info window? A bit like the list on the left here: 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/examples/speed_test_example.html

Comment: I believe that when you click on a link from the list, it calls a javascript function with some parameters (id, positions, ...) to identify the link clicked, and the function centers the map based on the corresponding marker... anyhow that is how I would implement such a functionality.

Comment: If I had, I would send you a link, but I do not ;)

Comment: OK, i guess there is a limit on the help one man can give. thanks anyway :)